# How do I make the entire tingle modal containing an image visible on load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, scrollbar

On load and if browser width is greater than 540px, the modal containing an image is cut-off *(see figure below)*. What should I do to make the vertical scroll-bar **immediately** appear?

[image: Image is cut-off]

This existing project that I'm working on is using [tingle modal plug-in](https://tingle.robinparisi.com/). It is linked like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tingle.min.css">
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        img {
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Tingle Modal</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="tingle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="modal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`modal.js` is where I create the modal containing the image:

```
function createModal(content) {
    let $modal = new tingle.modal({
        footer: false,
        stickyFooter: false,
        closeMethods: ["overlay", "button", "escape"],
        closeLabel: "Close",
        cssClass: ["modal"],
        beforeClose: function() {
            return true; // close the modal
        },
        onClose: function() {
            $modal.destroy();
        }
    });
    $modal.setContent(content);
    $modal.open();
}

createModal("<div id='modal'><img id='sample' src='sample.jpg' /></div>");
console.log(document.getElementById("sample").offsetHeight);
```

I noticed that when you zoom-in or zoom-out, or resize the browser, I then get the expected behavior of having the scroll-bar. I also noticed that on load, the image height is 0. I can't set the image height to a pixel value because I'll have several modals containing different images that vary on sizes.

You can also see the behavior here: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-wilson-gsir8). Please do make the embedded browser width in CodeSandbox bigger first, then refresh to see what I mean.

I have tried the following. But it then adds the scroll bar even when the entire modal fits in 100vh, which is not desirable.

```
.tingle-modal {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the code in `tingle.min.js`. It checks if the height of the modal overflows, if so, it adds a `tingle-modal--overflow` class. However, the image isn't loaded yet when it checked the height. So I had to redo the checking after calling the `createModal` function like so:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].onload = function() {
    const $modal = document.getElementsByClassName("tingle-modal")[0];
    if (window.innerHeight <= $modal.clientHeight)
        $modal.classList.add("tingle-modal--overflow");
};
```

Here's a jQuery version of the solution:

```
$(".tingle-modal-box img").on("load", function() {
    const $modal = $(".tingle-modal");
    if (window.innerHeight <= $modal.height())
        $modal.addClass("tingle-modal--overflow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these styles

```
.tingle-modal {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

If you need to save the position of the close button, then add:

```
.tingle-modal__close {
    position: sticky;
    align-self: end;
}
```

And instead of

```
  createModal("<div id='modal'><img src='sample.jpg' /></div>");
```

use it

```
const img = new Image();
img.onload = () => {
  createModal("<div id='modal'><img src='sample.jpg' /></div>");
};
img.src = "sample.jpg";
```

Comment: I want the scrollbar to the rightmost side of the browser, not on the modal itself. I've tried to set those properties on ```.tingle-modal``` instead, but then I loose my top padding.

Comment: It still removes the top padding.

Comment: @SatelliteSage, update and added image preloading